# $location in HTML5 mode requires a <base>

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I've added a [Tealium AngularJS](https://github.com/Tealium/integration-angularjs) lib from Github as a bower component to my SPA.  This instantly broke my unit tests.  I don't understand why as it should still be using the main `index.html` file which has a base href set already?

When I run `gulp test` form the command line, I get this error:

```
    PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 7 0.0.0): Executed 11 of 118 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.721 secs)

    PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 7 0.0.0): Executed 12 of 118 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.73 
    secs)

    PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 7 0.0.0): Executed 13 of 118 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.741 secs)

    PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 7 0.0.0) ERROR

      Error: [$location:noc:/dev/code/new-site-ui] $location in HTML5 mode requires a <c:/dev/code/new-site-ui> tag to be present!

  http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$location/noc:/dev/code/new-site-ui
  at c:/dev/code/new-site-ui/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12197

PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 7 0.0.0): Executed 13 of 118 ERROR (0 secs / 0.741 secs)

PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 7 0.0.0): Executed 13 of 118 ERROR (0.004 secs / 0.741 secs)

[13:03:12] 'test' errored after 3.67 s
[13:03:12] Error: Failed 1 tests.

    at c:\dev\code\new-site-ui\gulp\unit-tests.js:41:58
    at removeAllListeners (c:\dev\code\new-site-ui\node_modules\karma\lib\server.js:336:7)
    at Server.<anonymous> (c:\dev\code\new-site-ui\node_modules\karma\lib\server.js:347:9)
    at Server.g (events.js:199:16)
    at Server.emit (events.js:129:20)
    at net.js:1421:10
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have been fighting with this for 2 days..  Anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: If you're asking that means that your have a `<base>` tag, right?

Comment: yes.. in the main index.html  All test run fine but when I added the github lib it fails when it comes to its turn for test

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Are you really sure you have `<base href="/">` in your HTML `<head>`?

To avoid the need for a `<base>` element you can add this to your angular module config:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
  enabled: true,
  requireBase: false
});
```

doc: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$location/nobase

Comment: I have tried that and of course it works.. But turning off requireBase from what I read is bad for google when it comes to crawl your site and resolving relative paths in IE9?

Comment: Someone just suggested that Jasmine may create an index.html when running unit test which might not have the base href set?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not familiar with how Jasmine and PhantomJS interract but indeed if a different html file is created you may need to look for phantomJS doc on how to setup the page meta. Sorry I can't help more. (Alternatively I recommend protractor for end to end testing and jasmine/karma for services unit tests)